# What is the right way to use transaction using HTTP API?

Tags: orientdb

I'm using OrientDb 2.2.3. When I request `batch` command with transaction, it leaves warning log.

**edited**
I found that it only occurred when the transaction contains `DELETE EDGE` statement. So I edited script bellow.

[batch script]

`` BEGIN;
LET $a = CREATE VERTEX A SET foo='bar';
LET $b = CREATE VERTEX B SET bar='foo';
DELETE EDGE `Goes` TO #20:0;
CREATE EDGE `Goes` FROM $a TO $b;
COMMIT;
SELECT FROM $a; ``

[log]

> WARNI {db=test} Auto transaction starting is turned off for the graph, but already started transaction is left open.Commit it manually or consider disabling auto transactions while creating the graph or its factory. [OrientGraph]

I've never seen this warning until 2.1.x.

Is there something wrong with my sql code? Do I need to set other settings to avoid that warning?

Comment: You can ignore the WARN (we removed in 2.2.4-SNAPSHOT, it will be release next week).

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks.